# Find and replace specific character sequence in string and replace with different character sequence as you type

Tags: javascript, string

Ok I have a situation where customer's of ours can construct a text and with in that text enter in specified short codes to be replaced with data from the database.

For instance:

```
[f], thanks for supporting our organization. Tap here: [u] to enter your donation.
```

would be sent as

```
Jamie, thanks for supporting our organization. Tap here: https://cbo.io/oh98eI to enter your donation.
```

I need to be able to look for and correct certain errors in the typing as they type. Specifically, if the type [u] followed by any character but a space I want to be able to automatically put a space in there for them. I thought I had it with this.

```
if (msg.indexOf('[u]') >= 0) {
  if (msg.match(/\[u\][^\s]/g).length) {
    vmsg = msg.replace('[u]', '[u] ');
    msg_len = msg.length;
    v$('#message_text').val(msg);
  }
}
```

but the problem I am seeing is as soon as I change the `[u].` to `[u] .` Javascript now renders an "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null" because of the second if statement of `msg.match` etc.

I also have another check similar to this one and if I use both of them the second one doesn't get recognized because of the error. How do I write this so that it does not cause this error.

The next problem I have is if I want to use the same short code twice and I try to enter a character after the second one the replace only replaces the first occurrence so that I end up with `[u]` and a bunch of space for the first one and the second one remains `[u].` with no change. Is there a way to get it so that it will replace the one with the discrepancy rather than the one that is ok.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `vmsg` after the `replace`? Also, why are you only replacing the first match instead of all of them?

Comment: I'm not sure about the vmsg. I am attempting to replace all matches but am unsure of how to do that.

Comment: `.replace()` only replaces the first match when the first argument is a string. The only way to replace all matches is with a regexp with the `g` modifier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to use `.length`. `match()` returns `null` when there's no match, and returns a non-empty array when there's a match, so just test the return value itself instead of its length. There's also no need to use the `g` modifier; you only care if there's at least one match, you don't need to return all of them (since you're not actually using the returned value).

```
if (msg.match(/\[u\]\S/)) {
```

and `[^\s]` can be simplified to `\S`.